# Calculate correlation with cor(), only for numerical columns

Tags: r, correlation

I have a dataframe and would like to calculate the [correlation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.html) (with Spearman, data is categorical and ranked) but only for a subset of columns. I tried with all, but R's [cor](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/cor.html)() function only accepts numerical data (x must be numeric, says the error message), even if Spearman is used.

One brute approach is to delete the non-numerical columns from the dataframe. This is not as elegant, for speed I still don't want to calculate correlations between *all* columns.

I hope there is a way to simply say "calculate correlations for columns x, y, z". Column references could by number or by name. I suppose the flexible way to provide them would be through a vector.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: *"data is categorical and ranked"* is called an **ordered categorical**

Comment: As to which measure of association is best to use: [Correlation between two ordinal categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133769/correlation-between-two-ordinal-categorical-variables)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

if you have a dataframe where some columns are numeric and some are other (character or factor) and you only want to do the correlations for the numeric columns, you could do the following:

```
set.seed(10)

x = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10))
x$L1 = letters[1:10]
x$L2 = letters[11:20]

cor(x)

Error in cor(x) : 'x' must be numeric
```

but

```
cor(x[sapply(x, is.numeric)])

             V1         V2          V3          V4          V5          V6          V7
V1   1.00000000  0.3025766 -0.22473884 -0.72468776  0.18890578  0.14466161  0.05325308
V2   0.30257657  1.0000000 -0.27871430 -0.29075170  0.16095258  0.10538468 -0.15008158
V3  -0.22473884 -0.2787143  1.00000000 -0.22644156  0.07276013 -0.35725182 -0.05859479
V4  -0.72468776 -0.2907517 -0.22644156  1.00000000 -0.19305921  0.16948333 -0.01025698
V5   0.18890578  0.1609526  0.07276013 -0.19305921  1.00000000  0.07339531 -0.31837954
V6   0.14466161  0.1053847 -0.35725182  0.16948333  0.07339531  1.00000000  0.02514081
V7   0.05325308 -0.1500816 -0.05859479 -0.01025698 -0.31837954  0.02514081  1.00000000
V8   0.44705527  0.1698571  0.39970105 -0.42461411  0.63951574  0.23065830 -0.28967977
V9   0.21006372 -0.4418132 -0.18623823 -0.25272860  0.15921890  0.36182579 -0.18437981
V10  0.02326108  0.4618036 -0.25205899 -0.05117037  0.02408278  0.47630138 -0.38592733
              V8           V9         V10
V1   0.447055266  0.210063724  0.02326108
V2   0.169857120 -0.441813231  0.46180357
V3   0.399701054 -0.186238233 -0.25205899
V4  -0.424614107 -0.252728595 -0.05117037
V5   0.639515737  0.159218895  0.02408278
V6   0.230658298  0.361825786  0.47630138
V7  -0.289679766 -0.184379813 -0.38592733
V8   1.000000000  0.001023392  0.11436143
V9   0.001023392  1.000000000  0.15301699
V10  0.114361431  0.153016985  1.00000000
```

Comment: if you really only want to do the correlation on columns 1, 3, and 10, you could always do `cor(x[c(1, 3, 10)])`

Comment: Sorry, this is for numeric, not non-numeric data. I'll leave it just in case.

Comment: glad you left it, Greg. You already helped someone – it already helped me to se sapply in another creative way :)

Answer (score 17):

For numerical data you have the solution. But it is categorical data, you said. Then life gets a bit more complicated...

Well, first : The amount of association between two categorical variables is not measured with a Spearman rank correlation, but with a Chi-square test for example.  Which is logic actually. Ranking means there is some order in your data. Now tell me which is larger, yellow or red? I know, sometimes R does perform a spearman rank correlation on categorical data. If I code yellow 1 and red 2, R would consider red larger than yellow.

So, forget about Spearman for categorical data. I'll demonstrate the chisq-test and how to choose columns using combn(). But you would benefit from a bit more time with Agresti's book :
[http://www.amazon.com/Categorical-Analysis-Wiley-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471360937](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471360937)

```
set.seed(1234)
X <- rep(c("A","B"),20)
Y <- sample(c("C","D"),40,replace=T)

table(X,Y)
chisq.test(table(X,Y),correct=F)
# I don't use Yates continuity correction

#Let's make a matrix with tons of columns

Data <- as.data.frame(
          matrix(
            sample(letters[1:3],2000,replace=T),
            ncol=25
          )
        )

# You want to select which columns to use
columns <- c(3,7,11,24)
vars <- names(Data)[columns]

# say you need to know which ones are associated with each other.
out <-  apply( combn(columns,2),2,function(x){
          chisq.test(table(Data[,x[1]],Data[,x[2]]),correct=F)$p.value
        })

out <- cbind(as.data.frame(t(combn(vars,2))),out)
```

Then you should get :

```
> out
   V1  V2       out
1  V3  V7 0.8116733
2  V3 V11 0.1096903
3  V3 V24 0.1653670
4  V7 V11 0.3629871
5  V7 V24 0.4947797
6 V11 V24 0.7259321
```

Where V1 and V2 indicate between which variables it goes, and "out" gives the p-value for  association. Here all variables are independent. Which you would expect, as I created the data at random.

Comment: Sorry, I have the tendency to nest functions quite often to avoid too many idle variables in my workspace. If you can't make sense of the code, just ask and I'll explain what it does.

Comment: thanks. I actually forgot to mention in the question that the data is categorical but ranked (the level of approval with something).  You get a vote nonetheless for the code (from which I'll learn stuff anyway) and for the book reference.

Comment: ah, OK. That explains :-) Sorry for the lecture then, no harm meant.  I can definitely recommend Agresti anyway. It's the standard when it comes down to categorical data analysis.

Comment: Great answer, I could not find a better example to accomplish this task. One question, what values of p-value would indicate dependent variables?

Comment: @Eduardo a chi-squared test gives a significant result when there is a dependency between both dimensions of the table. See it as a simple 'regression': that's also a dependency between an X and a Y. Which p-value that is, depends on the data and how you deal with multiple testing. But for that, I actually refered to a great book.

Answer (score 2):

I found an easier way by looking at the R script generated by Rattle. It looks like below:

```
correlations <- cor(mydata[,c(1,3,5:87,89:90,94:98)], use="pairwise", method="spearman")
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what [Greg wrote in a comment for his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571909/r-how-to-calculate-correlation-cor-for-only-a-subset-of-columns/3572115#3572115).

Comment: Ah, OK, I got sidetracked by the use of sapply().

Comment: It's better to have a generic method that finds all the numeric columns, rather than hardcoding the column indices in (what if you added/ removed a categorical column? or inserted/removed non-categorical columns? any of that would break this code)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to just use the excellent `corrr` package https://github.com/drsimonj/corrr and do

```
require(corrr)
require(dplyr)

myData %>% 
   select(x,y,z) %>%  # or do negative or range selections here
   correlate() %>%
   rearrange() %>%  # rearrange by correlations
   shave() # Shave off the upper triangle for a cleaner result
```

Steps 3 and 4 are entirely optional and are just included to demonstrate the usefulness of the package.

Answer (score 1):

I will use the same data that Greg used above. We can use library tidyverse to select numerical columns first, then compute the correlations between these columns

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gdata)  # to use lowerTriangle function
set.seed(10)

x = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 10))
x$L1 = letters[1:10]
x$L2 = letters[11:20]
# Then compute the correlation matrix
corr_matrix <- x %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor(method="pearson", use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

You will get

```
corr_matrix
             V1         V2          V3          V4          V5          V6          V7
V1   1.00000000  0.3025766 -0.22473884 -0.72468776  0.18890578  0.14466161  0.05325308
V2   0.30257657  1.0000000 -0.27871430 -0.29075170  0.16095258  0.10538468 -0.15008158
V3  -0.22473884 -0.2787143  1.00000000 -0.22644156  0.07276013 -0.35725182 -0.05859479
V4  -0.72468776 -0.2907517 -0.22644156  1.00000000 -0.19305921  0.16948333 -0.01025698
V5   0.18890578  0.1609526  0.07276013 -0.19305921  1.00000000  0.07339531 -0.31837954
V6   0.14466161  0.1053847 -0.35725182  0.16948333  0.07339531  1.00000000  0.02514081
V7   0.05325308 -0.1500816 -0.05859479 -0.01025698 -0.31837954  0.02514081  1.00000000
V8   0.44705527  0.1698571  0.39970105 -0.42461411  0.63951574  0.23065830 -0.28967977
V9   0.21006372 -0.4418132 -0.18623823 -0.25272860  0.15921890  0.36182579 -0.18437981
V10  0.02326108  0.4618036 -0.25205899 -0.05117037  0.02408278  0.47630138 -0.38592733
              V8           V9         V10
V1   0.447055266  0.210063724  0.02326108
V2   0.169857120 -0.441813231  0.46180357
V3   0.399701054 -0.186238233 -0.25205899
V4  -0.424614107 -0.252728595 -0.05117037
V5   0.639515737  0.159218895  0.02408278
V6   0.230658298  0.361825786  0.47630138
V7  -0.289679766 -0.184379813 -0.38592733
V8   1.000000000  0.001023392  0.11436143
V9   0.001023392  1.000000000  0.15301699
V10  0.114361431  0.153016985  1.00000000
```

This correlation matrix is symmetric. We can do some other cleaning to have  a table with the names of each column pair and their correlation:

```
lowerTriangle(corr_matric, diag = TRUE) <- 0 
corr_matrix <- corr_matrix %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate(var1 = row.names(.)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-var1, names_to = "var2", values_to = "cor") %>%
  filter(cor != 0)
```

Then we will have:

```
corr_matrix
 var1  var2      cor
   <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 V1    V2     0.303 
 2 V1    V3    -0.225 
 3 V1    V4    -0.725 
 4 V1    V5     0.189 
 5 V1    V6     0.145 
 6 V1    V7     0.0533
 7 V1    V8     0.447 
 8 V1    V9     0.210 
 9 V1    V10    0.0233
10 V2    V3    -0.279 
# ... with 35 more rows
```

NOTE: In the above code, I use

```
corr_matrix <- x %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor(method="pearson", use="pairwise.complete.obs")
```

even though we don't have missing values in this synthesis data, we might need to consider an adequate value for the argument `use`, you can read about [Pairwise-complete correlation considered dangerous](http://bwlewis.github.io/covar/missing.html)