# How do I subset my data.frame by field type (e.g., numeric, character)?

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to subset my `data.frame`, `DATA`, into numeric fields and factor-type fields. My goal is to write generalized scripts to summarize my data, however, certain functions, such as `hist` or `quantile`, are not appropriate for non-numeric data. And it would make more sense to run table on the factor-type fields.

I tried using

```
types <- apply( DATA, 2, typeof)
```

to create a list of types for each field which I could then subset `DATA` by. However, this only caused errors. I'm sure there is a simply way of doing this but I've done a lot of searching and can't come up with anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried lapply(data,class)?

Comment: Was going to write that as an answer but perhaps you should?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571909/r-how-to-calculate-correlation-cor-for-only-a-subset-of-columns/3572115#3572115

Comment: Thanks, diliop. I think that's just what I needed.

Comment: @Benjamin. Also check the functions `numcolwise` and `catcolwise` in the `plyr` package, which can take a function and apply it to select columns.

Comment: @DWin Thanks, just posted it as answer

Comment: @Benjamin If this solved your problem, you might want to accept the answer

Comment: **Never use `apply` to iterate over `data.frame` columns!** `apply` convert `data.frame` to matrix in first step. It will totally mess your data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Since it worked, I'm posting my comment as an answer to this:]

Try `lapply(DATA,class)`