# Spearman's rho between ordered factors in R

Tags: r, correlation, ordinal

I have two ordered factors and simply want to find Spearman's rho between them.

However:

```
> cor(dat$UEMS.2,dat$SCIM23_SubScore1.2,use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="spearman")

Error in cor(dat$UEMS.2, dat$SCIM23_SubScore1.2, use = "pairwise.complete.obs",  : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

And just as a sanity check:

```
> class(dat$UEMS.2)
[1] "ordered" "factor" 
> class(dat$SCIM23_SubScore1.2)
[1] "ordered" "factor"
```

How do I find spearman's rho for ordered factors using R?

I did find the following:
[Calculate correlation - cor() - for only a subset of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571909/r-how-to-calculate-correlation-cor-for-only-a-subset-of-columns)

Which raises the same issue: R's cor() function only accepts numerical data. This doesn't seem right to me, because spearman's rho should be able to handle ordinal variables. Ordered factors are ordinal variables.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `pspearman` package to handle ordinal variables:

```
a <- factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1), ordered=TRUE)
b <- factor(c(1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3), ordered=TRUE)
library(pspearman)
spearman.test(a, b)
#      Rsquare            F          df1          df2       pvalue            n 
#  0.001015235  0.009146396  1.000000000  9.000000000  0.925904654 11.000000000
```