# R correlation on non numeric dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

I have a dataframe (screenshot attached) which is consists of both numeric and non numeric columns. I'd like to run correlation analysis on the whole data frame and get correlation matrix. However, when I do this I get correlation results on numeric columns only.
Is there a way that R can automatically substitute  factor columns with numeric figures and run the correlation analysis on the whole[image] thing ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct to look for correlation between two factors using the cor function in R, so I don't think trying to use it here is a great idea.

[This comment explains why very succinctly, and gives an example of how to calculate relationships between such variables using a Chi-square test, so I'll just link that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3573254/1723604%20%22This%20comment%20from%20a%20few%20years%20ago%20explains%20why%20succinctly,%20and%20gives%20a%20nice%20example,%20so%20I'll%20just%20link%20that.)

Comment: Please don't post answers that only consist of a link. If you link to the answer of another question it is likely that this question is a duplicate and you should comment to that effect (when you have more reputation you can also vote to close as duplicate).

Comment: Fair enough - the question isn't exactly a duplicate, at least, not to the question asked in the link. The question linked is about using cor on a subset of a dataframe (just numeric columns), it's just that this comment goes into detail about factors. I figured it was more efficient to link to that (and give credit where it's due) than re-explain.